# fontsize setting with newcommand and newlength

Tags: fontsize, lengths, key-value

How do I set a `\newcommand` so that the field `#1`, which is calculated to be `1.2*#2` Optional? Something similar to the following commands, but that did not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength{\myskip}
\setlength{\myskip}{1.2}

\newcommand{\mysize}[3][#2\myskip]{{\fontsize{#2}{#1}\selectfont #3}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the first parameter to be optional you need to define what the default value is:

```
\newcommand{\mysize}[3][12pt]{\fontsize{#2}{#1}\selectfont #3}
```

So, now `#1` will have the value of `12pt` if it is not specified.

---

If you want to `#1` to depend on `#2`, you can use [the `xparse` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mysize}{o m m}{%
    \setlength{\myskip}{#2}%
    \setlength{\myskip}{1.2\myskip}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\fontsize{#2}{\myskip}}{\fontsize{#2}{#1}}%
    \selectfont%
    \textbf{#3}%
}
```

`\IfNoValueTF` is used to test if `#1` was specified, and
the `o m m` specify that the first parameter is optional and that the next two are mandatory. Using this with `\mysize{10pt}{Default First Parameter:}` and `\mysize[16pt]{10pt}{First Parameter Specified:}` yields:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlength{\myskip}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mysize}{o m m}{%
    \setlength{\myskip}{#2}%
    \setlength{\myskip}{1.2\myskip}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\fontsize{#2}{\myskip}}{\fontsize{#2}{#1}}%
    \selectfont%
    \textbf{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\Text}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed erat ante, elementum sed dignissim non, faucibus id eros. Nam gravida lacus non diam rhoncus quis facilisis augue congue. Mauris a sem arcu, eget elementum arcu. Curabitur pellentesque ultrices mauris, placerat volutpat nulla vulputate sed.}%

\begin{document}
\mysize{10pt}{Default First Parameter:}
\Text

\mysize[16pt]{10pt}{First Parameter Specified:}
\Text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that *might* work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Text}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysize}[3][1.2]{%
  \set@fontsize\baselinestretch{#2}{#2}%
  \set@fontsize{#1}\f@size\f@baselineskip%
  {\selectfont#3}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\Text \par
\texttt{baselineskip}: \the\baselineskip \par

\medskip

\mysize{14}{\Text \par
\texttt{baselineskip}: \the\baselineskip} \par

\medskip

\mysize{14pt}{\Text \par
\texttt{baselineskip}: \the\baselineskip} \par

\medskip

\mysize[1.5]{14pt}{\Text \par
\texttt{baselineskip}: \the\baselineskip}
\end{document}
```

The above example provides `\mysize[<factor>]{<size>}{<stuff>}` that sets the font size for `<stuff>` to `<size>` with a `\baselinestretch` of `<factor>` (default is `1.2`). This solution is based on the definitions of `\fontsize` and `\linespread` in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\linespread[1]
  {\set@fontsize{#1}\f@size\f@baselineskip}
\DeclareRobustCommand\fontsize[2]
  {\set@fontsize\baselinestretch{#1}{#2}}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can specify your font sizes by numerals or point size: `\mysize{12}{...}` is the same as `\mysize{12pt}{...}`. The disadvantage of this approach in general is that only the font size and `\baselineskip` is modified, and not `\parskip`. And, since paragraphs are allowed in `\mysize` by default (since we used `\newcommand`), line spacing between paragraphs will not look that great; this is already visible in the above example between `\Text` and the `\baselineskip` length print-out. Modification of the line spacing should in principle be handled by [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace).